# rgl vector diagrams: show right angles for orthogonal vectors

Tags: r, computational-geometry, rgl

In the `matlib` package, https://github.com/friendly/matlib/, I have a function, `vectors3d()` to draw geometric vector diagrams.

The following code gives an example figure showing a unit vector "J"
and some of its projections on the X, Y, Z axes.  In the calls to `segments3d`, each argument is a 2 x 3 matrix giving start/end coordinates.

```
if (!require(matlib)) devtools::install_github(friendly/matlib)
library(matlib)
library(rgl)

vec <- rbind(diag(3), c(1,1,1))
rownames(vec) <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "J")
open3d()
vectors3d(vec, col=c(rep("black",3), "red"), lwd=2)
# draw the XZ plane, whose equation is Z=0
planes3d(0, 0, 1, 0, col="gray", alpha=0.2)
# show projections of the unit vector J
segments3d(v1 <- rbind( c(1,1,1), c(1, 1, 0)))
segments3d(v2 <- rbind( c(0,0,0), c(1, 1, 0)))
segments3d(v3 <- rbind( c(1,0,0), c(1, 1, 0)))
segments3d(v4 <- rbind( c(0,1,0), c(1, 1, 0)))
```

[image: vectors 3D demo]

I want to add to this the right angle lines, like `|_` to show that pairs of vectors that I plot using `segments3d` are orthogonal.  I've drawn these in by hand in the following figure.  But I don't know how to compute the small line segments needed for a given pair of vectors in this form, say, `v1` and `v2`.  I'm willing to assume that each length of the `|_` segments is a small number, like 0.05.
[image: vectors 3D demo2]

EDIT:
The problem reduces to the following:  Given three points, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, find the points labeled `p21`, `p23`, and `p123` in the diagram below.  The first two are simple examples of finding a point along a line between two points, but I'm stumped on finding the coordinates of the third point, `p123`, that is the position of a point a distance `d` along a line parallel to the line `p2->p3` starting at `p21`.

[image: vector3d-diagram]

In R, what I have so far is

```
#' Find position of a point along a line from x1 to x2
point_on_line <- function(x1, x2, d, absolute=TRUE) {
    v <- x2 - x1
    if (!absolute) v <- v / len(v)
    x1 + d * v
}

p1 <- c(0,0,0)
p2 <- c(1,1,0)
p3 <- c(1,1,1)

(p21 <- point_on_line(p2, p1, .10))
(p23 <- point_on_line(p2, p3, .10))
points3d(rbind(p21, p23), size=10, col="red")
```

This gives me the following diagram.  Can someone help me complete it?

[image]

Comment: I received an acceptable answer to this question on Math Stackexchange, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569612/show-right-angles-for-orthogonal-vectors-in-3d