# Animating a Vector in three-dimensional space

Tags: r, animation, vector, rgl

I have question about animation of vector coordinates in given `x` `y` `z` coordinate with time. So far I stuck at making output for each row if `df` and assemble them as a `.gif`. [rgl vector diagrams: show right angles for orthogonal vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186711/rgl-vector-diagrams-show-right-angles-for-orthogonal-vectors?rq=1)

What I want to do it is closer to this [Spherical Coordinate System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiQWcD25K0w)  video. But I dont need to the coordinate system to be rotated. Only vector rotation with time is enough for now.

Here is the example `df` for `x` ,`y`, `z` vector

```
time <- seq(1,30,0.1)
x <- runif(291,-0.14,0.1)
y <- runif(291,-0.14,0.1)
z <-sort(runif(291,-0.9,0.9),decreasing=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(x,y,z,time)

library(matlib)
library(rgl)

vec <- rbind(diag(3), c(0.04,0.09,0.85))  # just for example.
rownames(vec) <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "J")
open3d()
vectors3d(vec, col=c(rep("black",3), "red"), lwd=2)
```

[[3d vector in space][2]][2]

[image: 3d vector in space]

Comment: @jenesaisquoi yes . How can one make a frame for given locations?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Im asking about how to put those coordinates in `df` one by one to a `rgl.snapshot` ?

Answer (score 0):

See the example in `?movie3d`.  The function there rotates the coordinate system, but it can do anything you want, including redrawing the whole scene.