# .png output for each row of data.frame and making .gif animation

Tags: r, animation, png, apply, rgl

I have some trouble with generating .png  from each rows of data frame.

Basically, I want to `rbind` each one of the row of `df` to  `coordinate_sys`.

For each row of `df` together with `coordinate_sys`, a coordinate system and one a unit vector "J"  should be generated like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186711/rgl-vector-diagrams-show-right-angles-for-orthogonal-vectors?rq=1)

Finally, after generating a .png file for each unit_vector, I would like to make .gif animation.

here is the reproducible code of my script;

```
library(matlib)
library(rgl)
set.seed(12)
x <- runif(10,-0.14,0.1)
y <- runif(10,-0.14,0.1)
z <-sort(runif(10,-0.9,0.9),decreasing=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)


rot <- function(df,out){
  coordinate_sys <- rbind(c(1,0,0),c(0,-1,0),c(0,0,1))
  vec <- rbind(coordinate_sys, unlist(df))
  rownames(vec) <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "J")
  print(vectors3d(vec, col=c(rep("black",3), "red"), lwd=2))
 out <-  png(file="example%02d.png", width=200, height=200)
  dev.off()
}

apply(df, 1,rot,out)
```

Comment: what is the point of giving downvote?

Comment: You can try similar to [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgl/docs/rgl.postscript)

Comment: @akrun your previous answer was fine except so far no rotation is needed. Only one J vector shown in each plot. thaTs all I really want. In your answer all plots are the same except rotation angle.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason I deleted it.  Some bug in the code.

Comment: @akrun I still cannot understand what to do the link you provided. My task far more different the example provided there. I'm binding rows and want to execute function for each row. the example is plotting for whole df.

Comment: I think you can loop over the rows and export it to one of the formats mentioned  in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how far I got:

```
rot <- function(dat, i){
  coordinate_sys <- rbind(c(1,0,0),c(0,-1,0),c(0,0,1))
  vec <- rbind(coordinate_sys, unlist(dat))
  rownames(vec) <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "J")
  open3d()
  plot3d(1, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), zlim = c(-1, 1), type = 'n')
  print(vectors3d(vec, col=c(rep("black",3), "red"), lwd=2))
  rgl.snapshot(paste0(letters[i], '.png'))
  rgl.close()
}

mapply(rot, split(df, 1:nrow(df)), i = 1:nrow(df))
```

This code will generate 10 .png images with one vector in each and a stable coordinate system. (It generates warnings though.)

Now, we should be able to make that into a .gif using the animation package, but it fails on my machine due ImageMagick not wanting to read .png files (?). Perhaps it will work on yours.

```
library(animation)
im.convert('*.png')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and effort. I knew that making this code needs advanced experince;)